# Change variable width font to fixed width font

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a asp.net dropdown list control which consists of list of item name and price as follows

```
Pen     |  2.09
Book    |   1.2
Handbag | 30.50
Pencil  |  1.05
```

The padding is done so that the dropdown looks perfectly aligned but this works only for 
font-family: "Courier New" , Courier, monospace;
Now the whole page is using Arial font and the same is required for the dropdown, how can i go about achieving this?
So far i have tried wrapping each character in span tag using jquery as follows:

```
var array = $dropdownItem.text().split('');

var result = '<span>' +
              array.join('</span><span>') + 
             '</span>';

$dropdownItem.html(result);​
```

with hopes that maybe i can apply like a fixed font width to each character, but I dont know how to go about that. 
Apperciate any help.

Comment: What is the browser are you testing on ?

Comment: Google chrome, IE, firefox

Comment: Just to be clear, we are talking about a custom “dropdown” element here, not `select`/`option` HTML elements, right? (Because inserting `span` into the latter would be impossible.) So what’s the actual problem then – don’t know how to format them with CSS or what?

Comment: Why doesn't styling the `select` work for you? (`select { font-family: "Courier New" , Courier, monospace; }`; [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3uZJ4/))

Comment: I need to use Arial font to be consistent with the page.

Comment: But is it a `<select>`?

Comment: Its an asp.net dropdownlist control

Comment: @merazuu You never mentioned that in the question, nor in the tags. How were we supposed to guess?

Comment: i have edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found out that it is not possible to make the fonts display in same width unless it is a mono-space font. By definition, mono-space font means each character has equal width.